# Data migration of custom objects

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects, data-migration

Could you please explain and advise which are the best ways to do Data Migration in Production Envrionment. Before I start the data migration do I need an additional environment for backup? 
I am trying to redesign my Salseforce Production Envrionment and what I would like to achieve is to move data from custom objects to standard objects. For instance I have a custom objects like ISO, Competitors, APM Vendors which are of type custom objects. I would like to register and move them into standard Account object. Thus, fields and related lists will vary according to the type of the Account.
Could you please advise and explain what is the best possible way in terms of tools, practices which can help me import and export data in Salesforce?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to backup your data you can refer to this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_exportdata.htm). Also as I understand you will be only creating new records so you can just leave your old data there before you are ready to delete it. *(running forward it is easy to delete with Data Loader from your export files as you have Ids there)*

You can use [Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader) or some other tool like [Talend](http://www.talend.com/download) if you have some complicated mappings and want to perform some operations while you load. For your needs it should be fine to use Data Loader for export and Data Loader or Import Wizard to load new data.

So first you need to export all your data from those custom objects into CSV files or something similar and you are almost ready to load. I would create a checkbox field on your Account say `isLoaded__c` and in your field mappings set this to `true` this is useful because later you can easily delete all those records having `isLoaded__c = true` if something goes wrong. As you will be loading all into Account object there should be no troubles with relationships as you can also migrate them (i.e. Lookup on custom object will map to a Lookup on Account).

Here are some more materials that you might want to check:

- [Data Import Wizard docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=import_with_data_import_wizard.htm&language=en_US)
- [Data Import How-To Series(videos)](http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/ARIjWm2qrDkJVJxEhReFug)
- [Data Loader that you don't need to install (I haven't used it)](https://dataloader.io/)

Answer (score 3):

Import2 can assist with the migration and mappings of your custom objects to standard objects. Please feel free to start a free sample here: https://www.import2.com/salesforce. Once the sample is done, we can work together to review the mappings and your final import requirements.

Answer (score -1):

My name is Nataliia, I am a marketing manager at Data2CRM. If you want to migrate your data securely, you can consider using an automated migration service [Data2CRM.](https://www.data2crm.com/migration/) Besides, you can take advantage of the custom data import. Our techs can move the custom objects easily to fit your business requirements. Please, test the service in action and launch [a free Demo Migration.](https://app.data2crm.com/migration/wizard/9eb4df32836d980a96ee8db3da81274b504f3079#step=source)